# jsfiddle result different when viewing frame only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

So I have this design in jsfiddle.

It looks real nice in safari and chrome. However, with firefox, the regular page looks nice but when I view the frame separately, the font line-height seems to get messed up. The output on my website ends up looking like the "frame only" version.

Could anyone take a look at it and see if they could explain why this is happening?

Pay attention to the g's.

[looks good (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rY9um/3/)

[image]

[line-height messed up (jsfiddle result frame only)](http://jsfiddle.net/rY9um/3/show)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="formPage">
   <div id="formBox">
      <div class="formSection" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <div class="formLine" style="height:49px;position:relative;">
          <div class="indent">This is a needed label that I put over the textarea that describes what people are filling out.</div>
          <div class="whiteIndent"></div>
          <div class="borderIndent"></div>
          <div class="whiteIndent2"></div>
          <div class="borderIndent2"></div>
          <textarea name="text1" class="indent" rows="3" maxlength="360"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { }
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

#formPage {
  font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  width:910px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:30px;
  height:100px;
 }

.formLine > textarea.indent { 
   position:absolute;
   font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size:13px;
   background-color:#E2F4FE;
   width:818px;
   z-index:0;
   top:0px;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;
   border:0;
   resize:none;
   overflow:hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .formLine > div.indent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;background-color:#fff;padding:2px 2px 2px 1px; }
  .formLine > div.whiteIndent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:16px;width:820px;height:3px;background-color:#fff; }
  .formLine > div.borderIndent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:17px;left:0;border-top:1px solid #000;width:823px;height:1px; }
  .formLine > div.whiteIndent2 { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:32px;width:820px;height:3px;background-color:#fff; }
  .formLine > div.borderIndent2 { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:33px;left:0;border-top:1px solid #000;width:823px;height:1px; }

  .formSection { float:left;width:825px;border-right:2px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:13px;}
```

Comment: The two images seem identical to me. Can you, please, show where is the problem (or don't do that, if that's my issue, and everyone else understand it).

Comment: @dbanet look at the g's. On the second image they are cut off at the bottom while in the first they are in the center of the blue.

Comment: I really cannot reproduce that on my system: http://i.imgur.com/CBOAx3s.png

Comment: It looks like a bug on recent Mozilla Firefox versions. Try Firefox 17. I am using the ESR version on OS/2.

Comment: okay, I've just reproduced it on Firefox 24 on WinXP. That actally seems to be a font issue. I dunno what exactly has changed between the inlined frame and the same frame opened in a tab, but I wonder will it go away if you use another font?

Comment: @dbanet unfortunately I have to keep this font for the project

Comment: but please test it with another font.

Comment: are you using a css reset?

Comment: @dbanet I changed the font to Arial and it seems to work nicely so I guess it's a font problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a font problem. Must use a more browser friendly font. Browsers render font's differently and not everything can be exact when using certain fonts like `Arial Narrow`